# LineNumbers of an CodeView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

Whats the best way to represent LineNumbers next to a codeView? For [example](http://www.sublimetext.com). I'm relative new in xCode / cocoa programming so thanks for every help.

Comment: you want in xcode or textview?

Comment: yes I got your answer after 24 minutes. I deleted my answer without any down vote. That answr was about xcode.

Comment: Yep see it, but too late :)

Answer (score 2):

See NoodleSoft's example. 
http://www.noodlesoft.com/blog/2008/10/05/displaying-line-numbers-with-nstextview/

There was also a good example in a past WWDC.
Search developer.apple.com for WWDC videos and sample code.
Specifically look for Sample code: WWDC_2010_114
Year was 2010, session was 114.

Comment: I already test that with noodlesoft, but it don't work.

Comment: @Chryb What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? I've used NoodleSofts class before without a problem, so it certainly does work. What error messages do you get?

Comment: In the noodlesoft project I always get "The run destination My Mac 64–bit is not valid for Running the scheme 'Line View Test'.". If I put the code in my class, i get no error but there is no change in the NSTextView. I though that I implemented all right.

Comment: Alright, i create a new Project and put the same files like the noodlesoft files in it. I edit the .xib exactly and nothing happens with the NSTextView